# How to save Camera Image (together with images choose in phone gallery) to Firebase

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

so I'm actually doing this two method to **save images on firebase**, which is using **Camera Images** and also **Choose Images from Gallery**.

[image: app ui]

When I choose Images from Gallery, then click Button save I can save it right away. But when I click the camera button and then click Button save, the button is not functioning. Meaning like I didn't put any code in it.

This is the Method for uploading images:

```
    private void uploadImage () {

    if (filePath != null) {

        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading..");
        progressDialog.show();

        StorageReference ref = storageReference.child("winepic/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        ref.putFile(filePath)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                        String name = inputName.getText().toString().trim();
                        String type = inputType.getText().toString().trim();
                        String price = inputPrice.getText().toString().trim();
                        String description = inputDescription.getText().toString().trim();

                        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {

                            String id = databaseWine.push().getKey();

                            Wine wine = new Wine(id, name, type, price, description, taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString());

                            databaseWine.child(id).setValue(wine);

                            //Toast.makeText(AddWine.this, "Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(AddWine.this, "You should enter name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(AddWine.this, "Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent i = new Intent(AddWine.this, ListWine.class);
                        startActivity(i);

                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(AddWine.this, "Failed " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {


                        double progress = (100.0*taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()/taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                        progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded "+(int)progress+"%");

                    }
                });

    }
}
```

This is the code for OnActivityResult:

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){

        if(requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST) {

                Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
                final Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) bundle.get("data");
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);

        }else if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST){

            filePath = data.getData();
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I hope you guys can help me with this problem.

Comment: `if (filePath != null) {`. There is no filePath if you only used the camera.

Comment: so, how do i save it to firebase? that filePath for choose image from gallery. im using two method capture image from camera and choose image from gallery

Comment: Yes i know that you use two methods. Pretty clear. But you have no code to upload something if you used the camera. There is no code at all for it in uploadImage() then. You already said that too.

Comment: So what is it that you wanna upload after having used the camera? You did not tell us yet.

Comment: i want to upload the captured image (you can click link above for the ui)

Comment: Well where is it that your image is? Where did you store the captured image? What is it exactly?

Comment: I did not store the the captured image.....i seee......

Comment: Yes you did not store the captured image. Nor the thumbnail of that image. You only took the thumbnail as a bitmap and displayed that in an ImageView. So you have a thumbnail on an image view. But no full image. Moreover it is unclear what you wanna upload. A thumbnail only? Or a full image?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem** : You are not saving the `filepath` when you capture image from the camera.

**Solution** :  Change the code to:

```
  if(requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST) {

            Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
            final Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) bundle.get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            filePath = getRealPathFromURI(getContext(),bmp);
    }
```

Add this method to your class

```
 public Uri getRealPathFromURI(Context context,Bitmap inImage) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), inImage,
                "Title", null);
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse(path), null, null, 
                null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        return  Uri.fromFile(new File(cursor.getString(idx)));
    }
```

[image: error images for getContext()]

[image: error images for this, bmp]

Comment: (getContext(),bmp);      i cant solve this, its error. what should i do? thanks for this btw.

Comment: if you are using it in an activity pass `(this,bmp)` as paramters.

Comment: still the same, shows error the entire line. pls help me out~~~~

Comment: `shows error the entire line.` You can see that error. Yes. But do you think that we know what you see? No. You should exactly tell us the error. Exactly!

Comment: For the rest this stores only the thumbnail. So start telling what you wanna upload. The full image or thumbnail only.

Comment: `getRealPathFromURI` That is a ridiculous function name as there is no uri yet. It starts with a bitmap. And then it does a lot of things you would not expect if you only see the function name.

Comment: im so sorry for NOT showing the error that i ONLY can see, im so sorry for NOT do whatever thumbnail and image thing like u said. im using this forum to ASKED the expertise in this forum to help me out with MY PROBLEM. if theres no problem, then i will not clicking the "Ask Question" button. im only a STUDENT, not an expertise that already in this field for 100 years. I will improve the way i ask my question next time, thank you.

Comment: @Hana can u post the image of the error you are getting. thanks

Comment: @greenapps i am sorry. this function was meant for something else that i have to copy paste it here. You can edit the answer and come up with a good name if you want.

Comment: @M.WaqasPervez i attached the images above

Comment: @Hana sure thing.

Comment: @M.WaqasPervez can i get your email so that i can send to you my whole code? i really need your help

Comment: @hana m.waqaspervez@gmail.com

Comment: @hana you can send your code at : relsellglobal@gmail.com